# Getting blitting to work in funcAnimation embedded in PyQT4 GUI

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, pyqt

Starting with the working Matplotlib animation code shown below, my goal is to embed this animation (which is just a circle moving across the screen) within a PyQT4 GUI.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib import animation

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal','box')
circle = Circle((0,0), 1.0)
ax.add_artist(circle)
ax.set_xlim([0,10])
ax.set_ylim([-2,2])

def animate(i):
    circle.center=(i,0)
    return circle, 

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=10,interval=100,repeat=False,blit=True)

plt.show()
```

I am able to accomplish this using the following code, but there is one hitch: I cannot get blitting to work.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib import animation

class Window(QtGui.QDialog): #or QtGui.QWidget ???

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5,4),dpi=100)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)  # create an axis
        self.ax.hold(False)  # discards the old graph
        self.ax.set_aspect('equal','box')
        self.circle = Circle((0,0), 1.0)
        self.ax.add_artist(self.circle)
        self.ax.set_xlim([0,10])
        self.ax.set_ylim([-2,2])
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Animate')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.animate)

        # set the layout
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def animate(self):
        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig,self.animate_loop,frames=10,interval=100,repeat=False,blit=False)
        self.canvas.draw()

    def animate_loop(self,i):
        self.circle.center=(i,0)
        return self.circle, 

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I set `blit=True`, after pressing the Animate button I get the following error: 
**a.figure.canvas.restore_region(bg_cache[a])
KeyError: matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x00000000095F1D30**

In searching this error, I find many posts about how blitting does not work on Macs, but I am using Windows 7. I have tried replacing `self.canvas.draw()` with `self.canvas.update()`, but this does not work.

Comment: looks like I am following your footsteps: have you been able to find a solution on this?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time I managed to recreate the animation by using the underlying functions directly and not using the animation wrapper:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib import animation
from time import sleep

class Window(QtGui.QDialog): #or QtGui.QWidget ???

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)  # create an axis
        self.ax.hold(False)  # discards the old graph
        self.ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')
        self.circle = Circle((0,0), 1.0, animated=True)
        self.ax.add_artist(self.circle)
        self.ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
        self.ax.set_ylim([-2, 2])
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Animate')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.animate)

        # set the layout
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.ax_background = self.canvas.copy_from_bbox(self.ax.bbox)

    def animate(self):
        self.animate_loop(0)

    def animate_loop(self,begin):
        for i in range(begin,10):
            self.canvas.restore_region(self.ax_background)
            self.circle.center=(i,0)
            self.ax.draw_artist(self.circle)
            self.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)
            self.canvas.flush_events()
            sleep(0.1)

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Maybe this will be of use to you.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks so much!

Comment: Undetermined, I'm having a new problem with my axes not changing appropriately when I try to modify them before blitting (posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811952/deleting-old-axes-when-blitting-in-matplotlib-animation-embedded-in-pyqt4)). Have you encountered this issue before?

Comment: Yes I  have had this problem. No I have not found a solution. Sorry. I actually turned to c# in the end for the stuff i'm doing now. May look into this again later

Comment: Why do you give `animate_loop` an argument called `i` and you overwrite it immediately by running `for i in range(10)`?

Comment: @Guimoute that looks like a bug have changed the input to the function to do something useful...

Answer (score 4):

After looking at the source code of the animation module, I realized that there is an error in the Animation class (the dictionary bg_cache is empty, when it is accessed for the first time with blitting switched on).

This is fixed in the git version of matplotlib; however, in the most recent stable version 1.5.1, the bug is still present. You can either fix the bug in the matplotlib code itself or you can make a subclass to FuncAnimation. I chose that way, because it should still work after updating matplotlib.

```
from matplotlib import animation

class MyFuncAnimation(animation.FuncAnimation):
    """
    Unfortunately, it seems that the _blit_clear method of the Animation
    class contains an error in several matplotlib verions
    That's why, I fork it here and insert the latest git version of
    the function.
    """
    def _blit_clear(self, artists, bg_cache):
        # Get a list of the axes that need clearing from the artists that
        # have been drawn. Grab the appropriate saved background from the
        # cache and restore.
        axes = set(a.axes for a in artists)
        for a in axes:
            if a in bg_cache: # this is the previously missing line
                a.figure.canvas.restore_region(bg_cache[a])
```

Then, simpy use MyFuncAnimation instead of animation.FuncAnimation.

Took me a while to figure it out, but I hope it helps anybody.